# Need a lambda function to return all numbers that are between two float values, but there's multiple pairs of them

Tags: python, lambda, list-comprehension

So I have a column of a dataframe, I need to build a new column that basically bins values from the source column. Bin is determined based on whether the original value belongs to a certain range of numbers. Basically, I have this kind of list:

```
[(41.2, 44.1), (34.1, 38.2), (31.2, 32.4), (29.4, 31.2), (26.5, 28.6), (21.1, 23.5)]
```

I need the function to only return `x` where **41.2 < x < 44.1** plus where **34.1 < x < 38.2** and so on. Is it even possible to do within a lambda function?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
lambda your_list,x: x if len(your_list)==sum(tp[0]<x<tp[1] for tp in your_list) else None
```